# copy data from textbox to other textbox only affect first row

Tags: javascript, copy, row

i need your help, please. i have a project needing a textbox (outside table) copy its data (percentage value) to textbox (percentage) inside the table. The problem is the data copied only fill first row textbox table. i hope it copied to entire row table.

```
<table class='form'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Percentage input</th>
        <th>:</th>
        <td><input type='text' id='percentage_input'
    </thead><tbody>

<table>  
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width>No.</th>
            <th width>Percentage</th>
            <th width>Score</th>
        </tr></thead><tbody>";
        $i = 1;
$sql_data = $db->database_prepare("SELECT * FROM score")->execute()
while ($data_score = $db->database_fetch_array($sql_data)){

echo "<tr>
   <td>$i</td>
   <td><input type='text' id='percentage' value='0'></td>
   <td>$data_score[score]></td>
  </tr>";
}           
$i++; 
</table>
```

javascript

```
$("#percentage_input").keyup(function(){
    $("#percentage").val($(this).val());
    });
```

it makes me frustate, please give your advice...

Comment: Please open your page source and add the `HTML` code from there.

Comment: `<input type='text' id='percentage_input'`  not closing proberly

Comment: thnks prasad, i have correct <td>$data_score[score]></td>. but it still same problem..

Comment: thanks @lonut, but it still doesnt change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using unique id base on $i in the loop

```
<td><input type='text' id="percentage$i" value='0'></td>
```

then you can modify your js as

```
$("#percentage_input").keyup(function(){
$("#percentage1").val($(this).val());
});
```

if you want to to affect all displayed rows, use a class instead of id.

```
<td><input type='text' class="percentage" value='0'></td>

$("#percentage_input").keyup(function(){
$(".percentage").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thanks @shuan, but it still have same problem. how can i use uniqe id base on $i in the loop? and when i change id='percentage' id="percentage" it failed load the page...

Comment: i have changed become <td><input type="text" id="percentage'.$i.'" value="0"></td> and it worked only for first row when i used 'js' 
$("#percentage1").val($(this).val()); and when i change #percentage2 it only worked only for second row. Do you have any idea to modify this javascript so the entire row percentage follow the value inserted to percentage_input? i think u are missunderstand my question.

Comment: oh my god... thank you very much @shuan.. you're so helpfull.... it WORKS